# django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Unclosed tag on line 2: 'block'. Looking for one of: endblock. in django

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I am making a django app. This is my `index.html` template:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %} 
{% block content %}
{% if latest_post %}
    <div class="jumbotron p-4 p-md-5 text-white rounded bg-dark">
        <div class="col-md-6 px-0">
        <h1 class="display-4 font-italic">
            {{ latest_post.title }}
        </h1>
        <p class="lead my-3">
            {{ latest_post.body|truncatewords:30 }}
        </p>
        <p class="lead mb-0">
            <a href="{% url 'blog:post' post.pk %}" class="text-white font-weight-bold">Continue reading...</a>
        </p>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}

{% for post in posts %}  
<div class="row mb-2">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div
        class="row no-gutters border rounded overflow-hidden flex-md-row mb-4 shadow-sm h-md-250 position-relative"
      >
        <div class="col p-4 d-flex flex-column position-static">
          <h3 class="mb-0">{{ post.title }}</h3>
          <div class="mb-1 text-muted">{{ post.date_posted }}</div>
          <p class="mb-auto">
            {{ post.body|truncatewords:30 }}
          </p>
          <a href="{% url 'blog:post' post.pk %}" class="stretched-link">Continue reading</a>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Unclosed tag on line 2: 'block'. Looking for one of: endblock. in django
```

I have made sure:

1. All the blocks are closed
2. There is no whitespaces between the percent signs and the block names
3. I am not missing any percent signs

Please help me

Comment: seems like many of your `<div>` elements are not closed!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside for loop you have four opened `<div>` element after closing those it seems ok.

```
{% for post in posts %}  
<div class="row mb-2">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row no-gutters border rounded overflow-hidden flex-md-row mb-4 shadow-sm h-md-250 position-relative">
        <div class="col p-4 d-flex flex-column position-static">
          <h3 class="mb-0">{{ post.title }}</h3>
          <div class="mb-1 text-muted">{{ post.date_posted }}</div>
          <p class="mb-auto">
            {{ post.body|truncatewords:30 }}
          </p>
            <a href="{% url 'blog:post' post.pk %}" class="stretched-link">Continue reading</a>
        </div></div></div></div>
{% endfor %}
```